# Master of Shrouds Summon Undead caster level

Tags: dnd-3.5e

At second level *Master of Shrouds* ([LM p46](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CtQD3yVoKwEJ:dndtools.eu/classes/master-of-shrouds/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru)) gets *Summon Undead* ability:

> Summon Undead (Sp):At 2nd level and higher, a master of 
>   shrouds can summon one or more incorporeal undead creatures 
>   a number of times per day equal to 3 + her Charisma modifier 
>   (minimum 1). This ability is otherwise identical to the summon 
>   monsterspells, except that a master of shrouds adds her Charisma 
>   modifier (if positive) to the duration of the effect.
>
> At 2nd level, a master of shrouds can summon a single shadow. 
>   At 4th level, she can summon one wraith or two shadows. At 
>   6th level, she can summon one spectre, two wraiths, or four 
>   shadows. At 8th level, she can summon one greater shadow, two 
>   spectres, four wraiths, or four shadows. At 10th level, she can 
>   summon one dread wraith, two greater shadows, four spectres, 
>   four wraiths, or four shadows.

**What is the caster level of *Summon Undead* ability? What is its spell level?**

Given no rules clarification, I'll probably rule that it is equal to divine caster level, but I'm primarily interested in rules' viewpoint. As for spell level, 1 + 1 per 2 levels of *Master of Shrouds* seems a good idea.

Comment: Looking at the *summon undead* spells in the Spell Compendium (p215), summoning a single shadow would require the 5th level version of the spell.  So consider using something higher as your baseline.  (I think these spells are also in LM.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following general rule about Spell-like abilities applies:

> If no caster level is specified, the caster level is equal to the creature’s Hit Dice.

See the [general description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellLikeAbilities) of Spell-like abilities.

The spell level does not seem to be defined (nor is it necessary in this case).

Comment: It is, for the application of metaSLA feats. Thanks for the caster level tip!

Comment: @JeorMattan By the RAW, it looks like you simply can't use metaSLA feats on abilities that don't duplicate specific spells.

Comment: @starwed seems right, though the requirement is implicit and probably stems from the poor wording.

Comment: @JeorMattan If a (Sp) *doesn't* replicate a specific spell, it would be hard to gauge its power for the feats.  So perhaps a matter of expedience rather than poor wording.

Comment: @starwed if a SLA does not replicate a specific spell, a spell level equivalent should be stated in its description, for that very purpose. d20srd entry for SLAs implicitly suggests that (see save DC calculation).

Comment: @JeorMattan It would be a good idea for them to assign an effective spell level for the sake of rule consistency (and yes, MetaSLA). But, they didn't do that here, and there is no obvious default.